# Remote Debugging Typescript/Node Bot Framework Solution

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service

My solution is based on the Typescript version of the Virtual Assistant demo. It has been published to the resources deployed using the Microsoft provided ARM templates (.Net stack).

Initially, I attempted using VS Code's *Azure App Service* extension to debug, but I got the error that Azure Remote Debugging is currently only supported for Node.js version >= 8.11 on Linux. That makes sense, as the App Service is using the *.net stack*.

I have had some success using *Cloud Explorer for Visual Studio 2019* to attempt remote debugging of my Web App Bot in Azure. I've gotten the configuration to allow me to *Attach the Debugger*, and i take the extra step of *attaching* to the *node.exe* process but I can't hit any breakpoints due to missing symbols.

I believe I need to deploy a *debug* mode version of my solution to the Web App bot. This is where I am stumped. I normally use the VS Code UI to deploy/debug locally, so I'm not familiar with any commands that may work (nor do I see any listed in package.json).

How do I generate/find the necessary Symbols (.pdb or .dbg files for debugging and hitting breakpoints in VS 2019) for Remote Debugging my node.js/Typescript Bot Framework solution?

Comment: May I know what info that you want to check ? The info about Azure web app or something about bot framework itself ?

Comment: I want to check something about the botframework itself.

Specifically, i want to be able to debug incoming directline channel traffic, which to my knowledge requires the bot be deployed

Comment: Additionally, I've narrowed this problem down to be an issue with remote debugging Azure Web Apps that host Node solutions via IISNode.